# Can rpm call an external script stored somewhere in the package during installation?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, rpm, packaging

I have a package which is being retooled for in house purposes. Mostly making changes to the configuration files. The files need to be somewhat dynamic so changing the config files at source isn't really an option, as the changes would be a pain to change. Instead I want to run an external script in the `%post` section.  Is this possible?

I have tried a few options that haven't really worked. I read somewhere else I could call external scripts in the `%post` section, but I can't get a read on the working directory to do so.

When I reworked this same package for debian, the install scripts were relative so I could just call `/relative/path/to/ba.sh` but rpm works differently. Wherever I place the file it isn't getting called, and when I called `pwd` in the `%post` section I got `/`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please detail how you have packed and referenced the script.

Comment: I used the rpmbuild tools to unpack a rpm file, and am using rpmbuild to rebuild the file. I placed the script in a new folder in he unpacked rpm. I tried a few things to access the script, most recently I used `%{BUILDROOT}/path/to/script`, I think this fails because by the time it gets to `%post` that directory is cleared out. Everything works fine except finding this script.

Comment: If you know the exact `/path/to/script` where you're shipping the script in the RPM, why don't you simply run that, with the absolute path? Is the script shipped executable and with the right shebang line?

Comment: Also, you could try unpacking an RPM that already has a postinstall script and start from there?  You may see the differences then.  When you unpack, you could also try to enable debug output of rpm.